# Removing ambiguities in grammar

Tags: parsing, rascal

I have a simple grammar I've constructed with a problem I'm not sure how to solve:

```
start syntax Prog = prog: Type Id;

syntax Dot = {Id "."}+ ;

syntax Id =
    id: [A-Z_a-z] !>> [0-9A-Z_a-z] \ KW
    | Rv
    ;

syntax Rv = rv: "$" [a-z_A-Z][a-z_A-Z0-9]* ;

syntax Type =
    Rv
    | Ref
    ;

syntax Ref =
    Dot
    | s: "str"
    ;

keyword KW = "str" ;

layout LAYOUTLIST = LAYOUT* !>> [\t-\n\r\ /] ;

lexical LAYOUT = [\t-\n\r\ ] ;
```

The problem being that the we can resolve to `rv` in three different ways (`Id` -> `Rv`) and (`Type` -> `Rv`) and (`Type` -> `Ref` -> `Dot` -> `Id` -> `Rv`). The issue is that I need both `Type`s and `Id`s to be able to be `Rv`s. So, given a simple program:

```
$a x
```

My thought was the I could use priorities to fix this (but I guess I don't really understand what they do) by changing the rule for `Type` to be:

```
syntax Type =
    Rv
    > Ref
    ;
```

In the hopes that the parser would associate an `Rv` with `Type` before checking if it could be resolved in the `Ref` branch. I've run some ambiguity diagnostics but I'm not exactly sure what to make of these:

```
  info(
    "Ambiguity cluster with 2 alternatives",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the one alternative: Type = Rv ;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the other alternative: Dot = {Id \".\"}+ ;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the other alternative: {Id \".\"}+;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the other alternative: Ref = Dot ;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the other alternative: Type = Ref ;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "Production unique to the other alternative: Id = Rv ;",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  info(
    "The alternatives have different productions at the top, one has \n  Type = Rv \nwhile the other has\n  Type = Ref ",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  warning(
    "You should give this production a good label: \n  Ref = Dot ]",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>)),
  error(
    "To fix this issue, you could restrict the nesting of\n  Ref = Dot \nunder\n  Type = Ref \nusing the ! operator on argument 0: !labelX\nHowever, you should realize that you are introducing a restriction that makes the language smaller",
    |cwd:///grammar.txt|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>))
```

So, what I need is some way to `Rv`s to be both `Type`s and `Id`s without ambiguity when parsing. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you control the syntax of the language, you might opt for a non-ambiguous language by adding an explicit operator or some form of unique brackets or separator syntax. In other words, I don't think the grammar is accidentally ambiguous for a language which is not inherently ambiguous, and a non-ambiguous grammar should exist. I think the language as currently envisioned does not have a non-ambiguous context-free grammar.

An example fix:

```
syntax Type 
  = Rv
  | "&" Ref
  ;
```

Another way would be to try and hack your way out of this using Rascal's disambiguation mechanisms, but they do not offer any ordered backtracking behaviour by design. It would make the semantics of the grammar dependent on the parsing algorithm (which governs execution order of the grammar rules).

You could try and use `!>>` and `\` operators and `!` to exclude certain sentences and derivations, but if this could be done without loosing sentences from the language then the diagnostics tool would have given you the suggestion. So these hacks might solve the ambiguity, but they would also change the design of the language and make it harder to the programmer to predict what is allowed and what is not allowed.

The priorities mechanism does not help either, because it is designed only for mutually recursive rules to have a different priority, like `1 + (2 * 3)` vs `(1 + 2) * 3`

In short: I would opt for one or two changes in the language such that the syntax becomes unambiguous both for a general parser and for the human eye as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually working with the Java grammar and modifying it. What I posted was just a constructed example to show the problem. Unfortunately, I'm limited to what I can do with the grammar. One thought I had was to separate it in some way so I have a different `Rv` for `Type` and `Id` but this will cause the backend code I've written to need more changes. What I'd really like is some way to say "If this type can resolve to an `Rv`, then do that before checking for a `Ref`."

Comment: something like `@prefer` from https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/sdf2/filters/DirectThenCountPreferAvoid.rsc but I think this only works when you have productions with the same label. In the Java grammar it's used for `if` statements. Is that correct?

Comment: Sure, @prefer might work here. That actually just triggers a post parse filter which removes the other tree from the forest if the preferred one exists. I'd prefer not to use prefer but just write my own post parse filter, to really control it's semantics and to be able to produce meaningful error messages.

Comment: For @prefer to work you need two productions at the top of the ambiguous derivation to be different, and label one of them with'prefer'